# No sound in Skype

Tags: sound, skype

I have  Skype but it has no sound neither takes updates. Could you help me to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Login into your Skype account and click on Call => Audio Setting:

And check Microphone/Speakers setting from drop down list:

Also you can give a test call by clicking *Echo Sound/Test Service*:

[image]

For the Skype Update Ubuntu:

```
 sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list"
```

Or

```
 sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ `lsb_release -cs` partner' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skpye.list""
```

Or

Add the following line in sources.list file */etc/apt/sources.list*:

```
deb http://download.skype.com/linux/repos/debian/ stable non-free
```

The Try to update Skype:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install skype
```

Still getting issue then give try with.

```
 sudo apt-get install libpulse0:i386
```